# How to use OpenGL LOD in Texturing?

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

How do `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD`, `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD` and `LOD_BIAS` work?

To check it visually, i have created 6*6 texture with mipmapping and for values > 0.5 for `MIN_LOD` I get a 3*3 texture irrespective of values for `MAX_LOD`. If I change `LOD_BIAS` it does not affect my o/p. I am not able to figure out how it works exactly.

Can anyone explain it by stating an example?

Edit:
I am creating mipmap levels manually so that I can observe which level it is picking up. Here is my code:

```
glTexImage2D(target, 0, GL_RGBA,9 ,9, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE,subpix);
glTexImage2D(target, 1, GL_RGBA,4 ,4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE,&subpix[4]);
glTexImage2D(target, 2, GL_RGBA,2 ,2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE,&subpix[10]);
glTexImage2D(target, 3, GL_RGBA,1 ,1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE,&subpix[18]);
glSamplerParameterf(sampler,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD,0.862);
glSamplerParameterf(sampler,GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD,0.99);
glSamplerParameterf(sampler,GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS,0.0);
```

In this case I am expecting it would take 2nd mipmap level which is of 2*2 but It chooses 1st mipmap level of 4*4. When I set min lod < 0.5, It takes 0th level of 9*9. And it this happens irrespective of the value set to max lod.

Comment: Consult excellent Daniel Rakos' "Mountains demo" available here. Make sure to download the code, and read it, you'll find examples you're looking for.

http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/10/gpu-based-dynamic-geometry-lod/

Comment: @PiotrWadas it's geometry LOD rather than texture one. A nice article, but completely missing the point.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to do with these parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some references:

> **`TEXTURE_MIN_LOD`** Sets the minimum level-of-detail parameter. This floating-point value limits the selection of highest resolution mipmap (lowest mipmap level). The initial value is -1000.
>
> **`TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS`** specifies a fixed bias value that is to be added to the level-of-detail parameter for the texture before texture sampling. The specified value is added to the shader-supplied bias value (if any) and subsequently clamped into the implementation-defined range - bias max bias max , where bias max is the value of the implementation defined constant `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS`. The initial value is 0.0

So if you are surprised by the mipmap selection, I suggest following steps (not necessarily in order):

- Create mipmaps by hand so that they are visually distinctive from each other
- Verify your mipmaps are supplied correctly.
- Verify that your `LOD_BIAS` setting doesn't just put all of the values outside the range, making the sampler effectively always use the maximum or minimum LOD.

Searching around this, I've found [`textureQueryLod`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/textureQueryLod.xml). It might also be of some interest to you to aid debugging.